# Function as property of other Function - correct Definition

Tags: typescript

How do I define an interface for a function that has another function as a property? The example below does not work, the compiler complains `Property 'peek' does not exist on type '(name): string'`

```
interface MyReturnType {
    (name): string;
    peek(name) : string; 
}

interface MyEvaluator {
       evaluator(): MyReturnType;

}


  var evaluator = function () {
        var result = function (name) {
            return 'A';
        };
        result.peek = function (name) {
            return 'B';
        };
        return result;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to implement such a function in Typescript, but you can ofcourse build it up, just as you have. The problem is you have to explicitly type `result` as `MyReturnType`. Since the function you are assigning does not yet have the `peek` property, you could do one of two things:

- Make the `peek` function optional on the interface
- Use a type assertion to ignore the error.

I would use the second approach as you are currently building the function and you will assign the missing property shortly:

```
var result:MyReturnType = <MyReturnType>function (name) {
    return 'A';
};
```

Comment: This is more of a general problem I have with typescript - I will formulate another question

Comment: @Ferenjito The solution for this problem is the same, it you have an object that you are building that is not yet complete, the only way to initialize it with an object that does not yet conform to the interface is to use a type assertion. You could also use `Object.assign` as another answer suggests

Comment: I realized it is not necessary to have a library that I want to make a type definition file of, is syntactically correct typescript itself. It is only about its public interface.

Comment: @Ferenjito Not sure I got what you are trying to say. The public interface that contains a function signature and a method, is perfectly fine. This is an absolutely valid way to model this behavior JS in TS

Comment: Yes, the problem just occurs when I want to transform the library I am writing the .d.ts file for, in valid typescript (which is actually not necessary, but helpful).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Object.assign` to create hybrid types:

```
interface MyReturnType {
  (): string;
  peek(): string; 
}

interface MyEvaluator {
  evaluator(): MyReturnType;
}

const myEvaluator: MyEvaluator = {
  evaluator() {
    return Object.assign(function () {
      return 'A';
    }, {
      peek() {
        return 'B'
      }
    });
  }
}
```